# How to set arguements of python functions in the command prompt

Tags: python, arguments, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I hope to type in the arguements of python functions in the command prompt as following,
`python train.py --epoch 20 --batch_size 32 --lr 0.001` and so forth. On what should I consult to write my code? Thanks!

Comment: You want code to support --epoch etc? Basically, code so that you can pass those from command line?

Comment: @PySaad Yeah, so that I can type in the parameters from command line instead of an IDE or sth else

Comment: Use `argparse`. It provides a way to process your command line arguments into a set of values that you can then pass to your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below example -

```
import argparse

def some_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Some description')
    parser.add_argument('--epoch', help='Value of epoch')
    parser.add_argument('--batch-size', help='Value of batch size')
    parser.add_argument('--lr', help='Value of lr')
    return parser.parse_args()

def main():
    args = some_args()
    epoch_value = args.epoch
    batch_size_value = args.batch_size
    lr_value = args.lr
    print (epoch_value)         #prints your epoch_value which you passed
    print (batch_size_value)    #prints your batch_size_value which you passed
    print (lr_value )           #prints your lr_value which you passed


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Command line argument to be as -

```
python train.py --epoch <some_value> --batch-size <some_value> --lr <some_value>
```

***Reference***

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html